# How does this function called without an argument gets provided with one

Tags: r, ggplot2

There is this function from [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33179099/7082682) to another question that is given as the solution to generate the minor breaks of a logarithmic axis:

```
log10_minor_breaks = function (...){
  function(x) {
    minx         = floor(min(log10(x), na.rm=T))-1;
    maxx         = ceiling(max(log10(x), na.rm=T))+1;
    n_major      = maxx-minx+1;
    major_breaks = seq(minx, maxx, by=1)
    minor_breaks = 
      rep(log10(seq(1, 9, by=1)), times = n_major)+
      rep(major_breaks, each = 9)
    return(10^(minor_breaks))
  }
}
```

It is called in this fashion:

```
scale_y_log10(minor_breaks = log10_minor_breaks())
```

How does this work exactly? Where is the x argument coming from in the function declaration and how is it supplied when you call the function, since said function is called with no argument?

Comment: the docs for `?scale_continuous` says that `minor_scale` may be "A function that given the limits returns a vector of minor breaks" so `x` is basically irrelevant, it could be anything as long as the function takes one argument (or the first if two are given) and assumes it is the limits

Comment: @rawr So `x = c(min, max)`? Makes sense.

Comment: This pattern of function is called a 'function factory', i.e. a function that returns another function. You can read more about it here: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/function-factories.html. It is used a lot in the scales package that cooperates with ggplot2 a lot.

Comment: @tjebo I’ve linked to the original answer.